# repeated components conflicting with one another in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[This site](https://pluto.probono.net/massprobono) shows three identical components (on the right, in grey) that are generated with different parameters to give them different content and options.  (They are calling different APIs for their data.) They are contained in a master component, and attributes of that component control what to display, how many, etc. However, when one child component is displayed alone, it works fine, but when more than one are displayed only the first one works. Actually, it 75% works, but the mouse clicks on the menus don't do anything.

I ran through and made all of my functions and variables private before I realized that that sort of scope isn't enforced at runtime. To differentiate between instances in CSS, I add an incrementing ID to each component tag, as well as a class to indicate what sort of creature a particular instance is: Calendar, Opps Guide, etc.

Is this a concern, that one handler would handle a click from another component if they have the same name? If so, is there a way I can add a base value to each variable name and method name, which is incremented along with the ID? Or is there something else going on here?

Here's my code. The master component:

```
<div class="related-content" [class.toolkit]=
    "asCalendar.length > 1 || asOppsGuide.length > 1 || asProjects.length > 1 || contentTypes.length > 1 || displayLimit.length > 1 || title.length > 1">
  <content-display *ngFor="let t of title; let i=index" 
    class="{{asCalendar[i]? 'calendarApp': asProjects[i]? 'projectsApp': asOppsGuide[i]? 'oppsGuideApp':''}}"
    id="app{{i}}"
    [appId]="'app' + i"
    [title]="t"
    [asCalendar]="asCalendar[i]"
    [asOppsGuide]="asOppsGuide[i]"
    [asProjects]="asProjects[i]"
    [showNameSearch]="showNameSearch[i]"
    [contentTypes]="contentTypes[i]"
    [displayLimit]="displayLimit[i]"
    [locale]="locale"
    [pageId]="pageId"
    [topicFilter]="topicFilter[i]"></content-display>
</div>
```

... and the part of the repeated child component which is failing to fire (or firing and immediately toggling off or something. toggleFilterMenus() is being called, which I can see from a console.log(), but I don't know which component it is being called for:

```
<div class="filters" *ngIf="loaded" [class.menu-active]="filterIsClicked" >
  <span class="filter-indicator" (click)="toggleFilterMenus()">Filter</span>
  <span *ngIf="!isMobile() || filterIsClicked">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of menuArray" class="rcMenu" 
      [class.active]="menu.isDisplaying" 
      [class.radio]="menu.singleChoice"
      >
      <div (click)="toggleMenuDisplaying(menu)" class="hotspot" *ngIf="menu.displayArray.length">{{menu.label}}</div><!-- *ngIf="!asOppsGuide && !asCalendar"  -->
      <ul *ngIf="loaded && menu.isDisplaying" >
        <li *ngFor="let menuOption of menu.displayArray" (click)="onSelected(menuOption)" class="rcMenuItem" 
          [class.rcSelected] = "menuOption.isSelected" [innerHtml]="menuOption.label"></li><!-- | uppercase -->
      </ul>
  </div>
  </span>
</div><!--end filters-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a concern, that one handler would handle a click from another
>   component if they have the same name?

The answer is no. The scope between the 2 components is different and they shouldn't affect each other.
The problem is with your onOutsideClick method, more precisely with the `document.querySelector(".filters").contains(event.target)`

As you can see in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

> Definition and Usage
>   The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

This means that it will only select the first div with the class "filters". You either need to change your selector or replace document.querySelector method with

```
document.querySelectorAll(".filters")
```

You can find documentation regarding this on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp :

> Definition and Usage
>   The querySelectorAll() method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object.

I would however suggest replacing the selector to make sure that that precise section is being clicked, and not one of the other 2.

Hope this helps.

It would be helpful for next times to provide a little bit more code, not just bits and pieces. Thank you!

Comment: Ack, didn't see that. At least my instinct that scopes would be preserved was correct. Many thanks.